# Thymeleaf Set Binding for Neo4j insert

Tags: spring-mvc, neo4j, thymeleaf

I have been working on an Spring MVC application with a Thymeleaf UI. For Neo4j handling entities, I use Set that contains NeoImages that Belong to the class posts:

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NeoPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long postId;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 600)
    String question;

    /**
     * Images that are involved in that post
     */
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Relationship(type = "STARES", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    Set<Neoimage> neoimageSet = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * User that made this post
     */
    @Relationship(type = "OWNS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    NeoUser user;


    /**
     * Users that somehow in a way possible described in Userinteractiontype enum
     * with this current post.
     */
    @Relationship(type = "INTERACTED_WITH", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    Set<NeoInteraction> incomingInteractions = new HashSet<>();


}
```

Here the class of the NeoImage type:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Neoimage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long imageId;

    //For testing purposes use this type of information
    @ImageUrlValidator
    String imageFull;

}
```

Do not get me wrong I know that I want to use a Set to store the Neoimages in the Neopost class. The Problem is not the persistence or anything, but I want to delivery input results from a thymeleaf form.

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/postQuestion}"
                          th:object="${neoPost}" method="post" role="form">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('question')}" th:errors="*{question}"
                                       class="validation-message"></label>

                                <input type="text" th:field="*{question}" placeholder="Question"
                                       class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{neoimageSet[0].imageFull}"
                                       placeholder="Image 1" class="form-control" /> <label
                                    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('neoimageSet[0].imageFull')}" th:errors="*{neoimageSet[0].imageFull}"
                                    class="validation-message"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{neoimageSet[1].imageFull}"
                                       placeholder="Image 1" class="form-control" /> <label
                                    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('neoimageSet[1].imageFull')}" th:errors="*{neoimageSet[1].imageFull}"
                                    class="validation-message"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-lg-0 loginButton">Upload Post</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <span th:utext="${successMessage}"></span>


                    </form>
```

When I then access the post request, the question is filled in the model as expected, but the neoimageset does not hold the two strings from the two input fields. I have heard that databinding is somehow not possible to a set with thymeleaf. I can fully understand if you need any further elaborations, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using a wrapper method within:

```
/**
 * Wrapper method since set elements cannot be accessed by index which is needed in thymeleaf
 */
@Transient
AutoPopulatingList<Neoimage> neoImageWrapperList = new AutoPopulatingList(Neoimage.class);

public AutoPopulatingList<Neoimage> getNeoImageWrapperList() {
    //Copy content to neoimageset
    this.neoImageWrapperList.forEach(neoimage -> neoimageSet.add(neoimage));
    return this.neoImageWrapperList;
}
```

Now I just call the neoImageWrapperList instead of the actual set.